# Using Bluebird Promise in For Loop to build and return an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, zapier-cli

I am trying to build and return an Object using Bluebird Promises.
The Promise is a HTTP request which gets additional data to add to the Object.

I created a function that carries out a request in a for loop (I am also using a framework that carries out some middleware - this is what the `z.` is about)

```
const getWebAppCustomFieldDetails  = (z, url) => {
    const responsePromise = z.request({
        url:url,
        headers:{
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
     });
    return responsePromise
     .then(response =>{
      return JSON.parse(response.content);
     });
};
```

This function is called within the following code:

```
const webAppFields  = (z, bundle) => {
//This section carries creates an initial request which gets the bulk of the data
const responsePromise = z.request({
  url: webAppUrl(bundle) + '/' + encodeURI(bundle.inputData.webApp),
  headers:{
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  },
});
//This is an array to hold the objects created from the response
var fields = [];
return responsePromise
  .then(response => {

    response = JSON.parse(response.content);

    //From the response, append the core fields
    response.systemFields.forEach( function (systemField) {
      fields.push({
        'key': systemField.name,
        'required': systemField.required,
        'type': systemField.type.toLowerCase()
      });
    });
    return response;
  })  
  .then(response => {
    //Sometimes there are custom fields that need to be retrieved individually
    const customFieldCount = response.fields.length;
    var customFieldAppend = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < customFieldCount; i++){

      getWebAppCustomFieldDetails(z, response.fields[0].links[0].uri)
        .then(response =>{
          customFieldAppend = {
            'key': response.name,
            'required': response.required,
            'type': response.type.toLowerCase()
          };
          //This push doesn't updated the fields array!
          fields.push(customFieldAppend);
        });
    }
  //This return does not include the custom fields!
  return fields;
  });
};
```

I cannot figure out how to return the value from the nested Promise

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Promise.reduce](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.reduce.html) to reduce the list of promises you are creating inside the `for` loop into a single promise:

```
...
    .then(response => {
        const customFieldCount = response.fields.length;
        var customFieldAppend = '';

        // Promice.reduce will return the accumulator "totalFields"
        return Promise.reduce(response.fields, (totalFields, field) => {
            getWebAppCustomFieldDetails(z, field.links[0].uri) // Using the "field" variable provided by the reducer function
                            .then(response => {
                                customFieldAppend = {
                                    'key': response.name,
                                    'required': response.required,
                                    'type': response.type.toLowerCase()
                                };
                                // Add the data to the accumulator "totalFields"
                                totalFields.push(customFieldAppend);
                            });
        }, []); // The third argument is the initial value of the accummulator. In your example it is a an array, so the initial value is an empty array.
    });
...
```

`Promise.reduce` takes in input three arguments: the list of arguments to loop on (`response.fields`), the `reducer` function and the initial value for the accumulator. The accumulator (which I called `totalFields`) is the first argument of the `reducer` function, it is the variable used to reduce the values in the list in a single value. In your case the accumulator is an array (the `fields` array used in your example) so its initial value is an empty array.

Inside the `reduce` function you can access the single elements of the list (second argument) and you can call your async operation and fill the accumulator ad every step. The `Promise.reduce` function will return the accumulator wrapped inside a promise. For this reason your function can directly returns the `Promise.reduce`'s returned promise.